# Valid CA issued SSL certificate gives privacy error in browser

Tags: ssl-certificate, https, ssl-certificate-errors

(I had originally asked this question on StackOverflow and did not get any answers for more than 5 days. Since I found more SSL related discussions in this forum I deleted from SO and have re-asked here)

I have a valid SSL certificate for “services.infomotif.com” issued by "COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA”. Certificate is installed on a Jetty server at the URL https://IPAddress/ (this is a WebSocket service). I also have a redirect from services.infomotif.com to https://IPAddress through my domain name provider.

When I navigate to https://services.infomotif.com through Chrome browser it redirects to https://IPAddress:PortNumber/ correctly, but gives the error message “Your connection is not private”. The SSL certificate seems to look good.

I know I could accept the certificate through the Advanced option but do not want users to have to do this extra step. Are the warnings due to the way I have a DNS redirect to an IP address, or is it supposed to work as I expect it to (without the warning)?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the warnings are because you redirect to an IP address but the certificate is for a  domain name. This can't work like this, as the two don't match naturally ...

*Why* do you even do this? This looks terrible unprofessional ...

Answer (score 0):

After researching further I realized that I should not be setting up a redirect rule but rather just an "A Record" entry in my domain name server. Once I created such an entry the certificate error goes away and I'm able to access the service without any warnings. The Host record looks as follows:
Type: "A Record"
Host: "services."
Value: "IPAddress of back-end host"